# Domain fronting through browser context

Tags: web-browser

I am interested to see if it's possible to have domain fronting through a web browser, using any of its components (e.g. javascript) which can be utilized by the user.

For example, i've tried through javascript and XMLHttpRequest, but it's not possible to set the Host header due to "security reasons".

Are there any other potential ways to issue http requests?

Maybe some other header that is used by the CDNs to route traffic other than the Host header?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this question seems to be off-topic because it is about circumventing censorship, not information security. Maybe try posting it on Superuser?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially not domain fronting, domain fronting is when you use a legitimate domain like a public CDN to send messages, but they are afterwards redirected to you.

If a website has the same origin policy set to allow everything you can use XMLHttpRequest from the victims browser to access those resources. You can't set things like Host headers and cookies.

A good starting point regarding this is BeEf framework. 
https://github.com/beefproject/beef